# A responsive nav with vanilla javascript using matchMedia

Tags: javascript

I want to create a responsive nav but when I resize the window do not run my code, I´m using de function matchMedia

```
// Hamburguer
```

let mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 800px)');

let hamburgerToggle = (mediaQuery) => {

```
if (mediaQuery.matches) {
    let navItems = document.querySelector('.nav_items');
    let nav = document.querySelector('.nav');

    let hamburger = document.createElement('i')
    hamburger.classList.add('fas', 'fa-bars', 'hamburger');
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.appendChild(hamburger);
    nav.appendChild(div);

    // Toggle
    div.addEventListener('click', () => {
        navItems.classList.toggle('show');
    });
    console.log(hamburger);
}
```

}

hamburgerToggle(mediaQuery);
mediaQuery.addEventListener('load', hamburgerToggle);

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the change event instead of load.

```
mediaQuery.addEventListener('change', hamburgerToggle);
```

Comment: It worked, but now is creating hamburgers when mediaQuery matches

Comment: That's because you're creating elements inside the function. If that's not what you want to do, then remove/move that code.